# Como cerrar la etiqueta html </source> online

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml, svg

Hola estoy generando un svg al vuelo con videos con el código simplificado que indico, pero no consigo cerrar la etiqueta con php o javascript  para que el grafico svg sea visto, da error de sintaxis al no cerrar la etiqueta  y que sea recogido por un alert  por ejemplo

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function scripenvivo(){
      
 //var e=document.getElementById('hola');


//var textnode = document.createTextNode("</source>");        
//e.appendChild(textnode);  
var sor =document.getElementById('soyunsvgconvideo').innerHTML  
alert(sor)
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div Id="soyunsvgconvideo">
    <svg class="img-responsive" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1470 800 ">

    <foreignObject id="i" requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml " width="640" x="500" y="300" height="352" >
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" preload="auto" class="a64" width="640" height="352"> 
<source  x="300" y="225" src="https://animacionesweb.online/videos/City-3134.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 
 </video>
</g>
 </foreignObject>
 
  </svg>        

    </div>
    
    <input type="button"  onclick=scripenvivo() value ="pulsame"></imput>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No basta el ejemplo de código, necesitamos ver cómo lo estás generando para poder tratar de ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Acaso un `videoElement.appendchild(sourceElement)` no te funciona?

Comment: El objetivo es que en alert salga la etiqueta cerrada</source> gracias Maurico Contreras en principio no me funciono he modificado el codigo para que sea mas facil comprensión o eso espero gracias a todos

Comment: El problema es que dices estar generando todo "al vuelo" pero solo se ve el HTML estático y, si ese es el caso, bastaría con agregar ahí mismo el cierre de la etiqueta.

Comment: El grupo `<g>` que utilizas dentro del foreignObject es un elemento invalido. Borra el grupo

Comment: el objeto de este script que es el resumen de una pagna  de animaciones web y es obtener un  grafico svg valido para una pagina web en este caso lo hago a traves de un alet .gracias por vuestro interes